# oracle Apex interactive report columns based on list values

Tags: oracle-apex

In interactive reports I want to dispaly the deacription not the ID, I tried using the Plain Text(Based on List of Values) column type and it showed the decription how ever the records cant be edited now with 'ORA-01403: no data found'.
How can I achive this.
I am using APEX 22

Using the PlainText type the record will be editbale with now issues, but the column is showing the ID not the description.

Comment: What do you mean "the records cannot be edited now" ? An interactive report is always read only - it does not have any editing features out of the box.

Comment: so the interactive report has the edit button next to each record, when the primary keys are plain text based on value I will get an error 'ORA-01403: no data found'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use wizard to create [report + form] pair of pages; doing so, you'd get both pages working **properly**. Then you can make them fancy, if you want.

I don't know what you did wrong. I've just created an example in my database/Apex, everything works as expected.

- in shared components, I created list of values (`lov_dept`) as

  ```
  select dname d, deptno r from dept
  ```
- using the wizard, I created interactive report + form

  - source table is Scott's `emp`, with `empno` being the primary key column
- `deptno` column's type was "plain text"; it means that it would display e.g. "10" (department number)

  - as you want to display description (i.e. department name), column's type is changed to "plain text (based on list of values)"; I chose `lov_dept` from list of values for that column.

Run the page

- interactive report shows department **name** (e.g. "ACCOUNTING") instead of department number
- edit icon (in report's first column) leads to form page, passing `empno` (the primary key column) and fetching data (as expected)

[image]

---

That's what you should have done. See if you can find where you did wrong; if not, recreate the whole thing from scratch, following these instructions.

Comment: for me, the primary key is a composite of two columns one of which depends on a list of values, so when I click on the edit icon I get an error that the record is not found, since the apex is using the text in the report to retrieve the record to open the edit page.

Comment: If possible, create **another** primary key column (populate it with a sequence or set it to an identity column so that database populates it automatically). Two columns, which now make your primary key, should then be set to make a **unique** key (both columns should also be set to NOT NULL). Doing so, you'd avoid situations like the one you're in now.

Comment: Agree totally with @littlefoot. Having surrogate keys as primary keys has a lot of advantages. Avoid composite primary keys as a general rule.